# Change style of CSpinButtonCtrl

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, spinner

I have tried to change orientation property of CSpinButtonCtrl in C++ MFC.

By default I have specified orientation property as vertical, nevertheless when I try to change property style to horizontal (**UDS_HORZ**) during execution, it doesn't work...

**Sample code**

```
CRect rect;
CWnd *pWnd;

pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_SPIN_GRAD_CONTRAST);
pWnd->GetWindowRect(&rect);
((CSpinButtonCtrl*)pWnd)->Create(WS_VISIBLE | UDS_HORZ, rect, pWnd->GetParent(), IDC_SPIN_GRAD_CONTRAST);
```

It creates a horizontal spin button control.

What I pretend to do is find any way to change the style without changing position and behaviour of the control previously created

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Please edit your question posting the relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

Some styles of controls can only be used when you create the control.

AFAIK you have to recreate the control.

On the other hand I looked into the source code of the `CMFCSpinButtonCtrl`. Using this allows dynamically changing the orientation. Make sure that you force to redraw the control.

PS: Changing this at runtime seams to be a strange scenario for me.

Comment: How can I declare an object of CMFCSpinButtonCtrl type?

Comment: Declare an instance of the class and subclass your up down control.

Comment: I think that it's a complex solution, are there any easiest way which framework provides changing only `UDS_HORZ` style of CSpinButtonControl and force the redraw/refresh? I have trying using `SetWindowLong(...), Invalidate(), RedrawWindow()` but it doesn't do anything I mean.... Thanks beforehand.

Comment: No. It seams that this control can only be changed when the control is created. So if you want to change it, you have to recreate the control. You have to decide if subclassing isn't simpler. I don't know you code base, but in my programs it would be simpler to just subclass the control.